# Select dropdown using div to be selected by pupeeter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, puppeteer

Problem statement:

There is a dropdown created using material select. This dropdown is populated via API and ul > li's are populated in DOM when it is selected.

Tried so far:

Created a function which first click using MouseEvents and then selects a li with innerText as provided.

```
await page.evaluate((newSelectedValue, cssSelector) => {
  var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
  clickEvent.initEvent("mousedown", true, true);
  var selectNode = document.querySelector(cssSelector);
  selectNode.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
//Fails on below line
  [...document.querySelectorAll('li')].filter(el => el.innerText == newSelectedValue)[0].click();
}, newSelectedValue, cssSelector);
```

It was working fine. But recently it fails while clicking on the li and gives error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click')`
I tried taking screenshot before click, dropdown is correctly populated in the DOM and `[...document.querySelectorAll('li')].filter(el => el.innerText == newSelectedValue)[0].click();` also works when I tried in the browser manually.

Any suggestions what is going wrong because API is populating and DOM too has elements in it?

Comment: Please share the site and your code as a runnable [mcve]. Thanks. In general, `el.innerText === newSelectedValue` should be `el.textContent.trim() === newSelectedValue.trim()` since HTML usually ignores whitespace. You could also try issuing a trusted Puppeteer event rather than an untrusted native JS event. Finally, `filter(...)[0]` can be replaced by `find(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Puppeteer's `waitFor` methods to wait for elements (https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitforselector, https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitforxpath) and `xpath` to get elements based on text contents (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp):

```js
const ul = await page.waitForSelector("ul", { visible: true });
await ul.click();

const li = await page.waitForXPath(`//li[contains(text(), '${newSelectedValue}')]`, { visible: true });
```

or this way to get `li` as child of `ul`:

```js
const ul = await page.waitForSelector("ul", { visible: true });
await ul.click();

const li = await ul.waitForSelector(`xpath/.//li[contains(text(), '${newSelectedValue}')]`, { visible: true });
```